# Using OnItemClickListener with PopupMenu

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-menu

I'm trying to initialise a PopupMenu when I click an item in an item in a custom listview.
My onItemClick works confirmed by the logging.

However, I am unable to get the popup menu to work within my method. I do not understand what the correct context parameter is to the PopupMenu.

Given the error:

```
error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnItemClickListener> cannot be converted to Context
       PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, position);
```

Using getActivity() as suggested - [Error:(124, 62) error: incompatible types: Class cannot be converted to Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558893/error124-62-error-incompatible-types-class-cannot-be-converted-to-context)

Results in:
error:

```
cannot find symbol
                 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), position);
                                                 ^
  symbol: method getActivity()
```

What parameter should I pass in here? Or is OnItemClickListener even compatible with PopupMenu?

Below is the full method:

```
   private void populateUsersList() {
        // Construct the data source
        ArrayList<Issue> arrayOfUsers = ProfileActivity.getAllIssueList();
        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
        issueAdapter adapter = new issueAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers);
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

      //populate the listView
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Get the selected item text from ListView
                Issue selectedItem = (Issue) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.d("clicked",selectedItem.getIssueID());

                 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, position);
                //Inflating the Popup using xml file
               popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_listview, popup.getMenu());

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: why dont you use [Contextual Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#context-menu)?

Answer (score 1):

**this** in a nested class refers to the nested class instance, not to the outer class instance (MainActivity). Qualify it with e.g. **MainActivity.this** to refer to the outer class instance :

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, position);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me! Would upvote but I need a better reputation score for that...